Automating Custom Mediator install script Upgrade from WSO2 APIM 3.2 to 4.3
I'm in the process of upgrading from WSO2 API Manager (APIM) 3.2 to 4.3, and I'm encountering issues with my custom Java mediator. In version 3.2, I used a script to copy my sequences to the /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences folder. However, this approach doesn't work in 4.3 because sequences are now handled using a database.
To work around this, I modified the

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]

section by adding:
sequences = ["----"]

While this works, it feels like a hack, and I'm not comfortable with changing deployment files directly. Additionally, the policy doesn't show up in the publisher.
Given that I have many APIs configured, manual intervention is not feasible. How can I automate this process using a script in a more standardized way?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
